# Customer Access feature - Inline Editing - Custom Record

Tags: permissions, netsuite, roles, inline-editing, saved-searches

I created a custom record with 3 fields (Sales Order , Custom List & Date ) to display on the customer view .
I also created a search to be able to edit this record from the search result view.
When I am on the Netsuite (Employee Access), I see the Edit switch button And I am able to edit from the Saved search Result view.
But when I'm logged in from the client access, I am not able change the search result. Indeed the switch button Edit Line on the search result view does't appear.
The behavior I want seems to work only on the employee access.

- Inline Editing feature is enabled (Setup > Company > Setup Tasks > Enable Features)
- Inline Editing feature is enabled on Custom Record

Maybe it's something related to permission on the custom record or the Custom Role I created for customer access

Custom Record
[image]

Role Permissions
[image]

Comment: you haven't said what the actual problem is.

Comment: Sorry , I didn't noticed it before. I updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netsuite Customer Service answered me :

> I have reviewed your concern and I've found out that we have an
> existing Enhancement for this behavior.
>
> I have tried to replicate your concern in my test drive and I was able
> to verify that Inline Editing for Custom Records in Searches is
> currently not available - even if the role has Full permission to it.
>
> This is unavailable as the customer center is still not completely
> customizable and the permissions of a customer is very limited. The
> said feature that you are looking for is still unavailable.
>
> I will attach you case to the Enhancement, please see further details
> below.